# How to rate a post from Admin Side / Manually?

Tags: posts, custom-field, rating

I am working on a Mini Job Site.

i want to give rating to posts manually from admin / editor side

Best rated people will be on top. so visitor'll  get better choice.

visitor are not allowed to rate posts

like this

[image: please have a look]

how to do this ?

{1} Meta-box uses
{2} Custom Field

help me please

Comment: do you use some kind of plugin, if so provide link.

Comment: no Amit .. not using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something I'd use if I want to do that without using plugins

Create a custom field as `rating` and provide the value while doing post. Suppose I gave a rating of 6, Now wordpress save it into the database as.

- `meta_key` => rating
- `meta_value` => 6

Now to show the rating on post I'll use this code into `single.php` or `index.php` but make sure to put it within [`Wordpress loop`](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) -

```
<?php
    //grab the rating value
    $rating = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true);

    //prints star image
    for ($i=1; $i<=$rating; $i++){
        echo '<img src="LINK-TO-STAR-ICON"/>';
    }

    //prints unstar image
    for ($i=$rating; $i<10; $i++){
        echo '<img src="LINK-TO-UNSTAR-ICON"/>';
    }
?>
```

The above code will result like this - [image]

Comment: If that helped, consider up voting it.

Comment: Amit, Custom field not working if you can help me i m not very smart in php. 
 $rating = get_post_custom_keys();
  foreach ( $rating as $key => $value ) {
         echo $key . " => " . $value . "i+";
  }

Comment: what exactly not working. ?

Comment: custom field not showing in post section

Comment: My code works great on my site, Why you 're using that other code ?

Comment: please have a look http://www.tester.shreshthbharat.in/

Comment: i cant rate on post section some bug in custom fields

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4375/discussion-between-nisha-at-behance-and-amit)